# Google Cloud Platform Monitoring and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Hi guys i'm working on an app that uses the google cloud platform. I use the code below to get metrics on the system and i would like to display the metrics in a graph on the react website. The problem for a 12h small metric GCP sends me a json with 5000 lines with a bunch of stuff and i have no clue how to filter this out. I would just like a bunch of points with timestamps and values to put on a simple graph. It sends sooooo much stuff and so much of it is pointless.

```
try (MetricServiceClient client = MetricServiceClient.create()) {
            ProjectName name = ProjectName.of("geotrails");
            TimeInterval interval = TimeInterval.newBuilder().setStartTime(Timestamps.fromMillis(start))
                    .setEndTime(Timestamps.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())).build();
            ListTimeSeriesRequest request = ListTimeSeriesRequest.newBuilder().setName(name.toString())
                    .setFilter(stats.filter()).setInterval(interval).build();
            ListTimeSeriesPagedResponse response = client.listTimeSeries(request);
            return Lists.newArrayList(response.iterateAll());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new InternalServerException("");
        }
```

Here is sample from the spam output lines (id show it all but 30k chars is max and id had 200k)

```
[
  {
    "metric_": {
      "bitField0_": 0,
      "type_": "appengine.googleapis.com/system/instance_count",
      "labels_": {
        "isMutable": true,
        "mode": "MAP",
        "mapData": {
          "state": ""
        },
        "converter": {}
      },
      "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
      "unknownFields": {
        "fields": {},
        "fieldsDescending": {}
      },
      "memoizedSize": -1,
      "memoizedHashCode": 0
    },
    "resource_": {
      "bitField0_": 0,
      "type_": "gae_app",
      "labels_": {
        "isMutable": true,
        "mode": "MAP",
        "mapData": {
          "version_id": "1",
          "module_id": "default",
          "project_id": "geotrails",
          "zone": "europe-west6-3"
        },
        "converter": {}
      },
      "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
      "unknownFields": {
        "fields": {},
        "fieldsDescending": {}
      },
      "memoizedSize": -1,
      "memoizedHashCode": 0
    },
    "metricKind_": 1,
    "valueType_": 2,
    "points_": [
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710460,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710460,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710400,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710400,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710340,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710340,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710280,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710280,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710220,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710220,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710160,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710160,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710100,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710100,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710040,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590710040,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709980,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709980,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709920,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709920,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709860,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709860,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709800,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709800,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709740,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709740,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709680,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709680,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709620,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709620,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709560,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709560,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709500,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709500,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      },
      {
        "interval_": {
          "endTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709440,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "startTime_": {
            "seconds_": 1590709440,
            "nanos_": 0,
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
              "fields": {},
              "fieldsDescending": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
          },
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "value_": {
          "valueCase_": 2,
          "value_": 0,
          "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
          "unknownFields": {
            "fields": {},
            "fieldsDescending": {}
          },
          "memoizedSize": -1,
          "memoizedHashCode": 0
        },
        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
        "unknownFields": {
          "fields": {},
          "fieldsDescending": {}
        },
        "memoizedSize": -1,
        "memoizedHashCode": 0
      }
```

Any clue?

Comment: Would you please the metric name that you are considering here? I found this docs [link](https://www.loggly.com/blog/best-practices-for-client-side-logging-and-error-handling-in-react/) which might help you with logging and error handling in React.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems you are using Java guide from official docs https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics#timeseries-list-data - and it does not usually send back the fields you are showing - see in sandbox, https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list